# Django response setting a json as a cookie

Tags: javascript, python, django, cookies

I would like to set the value of a client side cookie from django as a javascript dictionary object. I know you can set a cookie value of a string like this in django:

```py
response = HttpResponseRedirect( reverse('app:home') )
response.set_cookie( 'cookiekey', 'value' )
return response
```

I can then read the cookie on the client side like this:

```
Cookies.get( 'cookiekey' )
```

using the Cookies library ( https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie )

What I am unable to do is set the cookie to be a dictionary/json object:

I have tried this:

```py
response.set_cookie( 'cookiekey', {'value' : 'value'} )
```

and

```py
import json
response.set_cookie( 'cookiekey', json.dumps( {'value' : 'value'} ) )
```

and then tried to read the cookie back on the client side using:

```
Cookies.getJSON( 'cookiekey' )
```

but this doesn't seem to give me back a javascript dictionary object (neither does Cookies.get) but instead a string:

```
var message = Cookies.getJSON( 'cookiekey' );
alert( typeof message );
```

Comment: Why are you using cookies for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your Python script to set the cookie:

`response.set_cookie("json", json.dumps({"foo":"bar"}))`

And use this in your JavaScript to get the cookie, using `JSON.parse` rather than `Cookies.get`:

`JSON.parse(Cookies.get( 'json' ))`

This worked for me :)

EDIT:

Use `JSON.parse(Cookies.get( 'json' ).split('\\').join('');` to remove all backslashes if that's an issue

Comment: This didnt work for me because I get the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 1

The pre JSON'd cookie string is:  {\"message\": \"bar\"} 

and even when i do ```.replace('\\','') ``` on it, it only replaces the first back slash

Comment: Sorry try replacing `json.dumps({"foo":"bar"})` with `json.dumps({"foo":"bar"}).replace(" ","")`... Does that work? It could be the JS JSON library being fussy...